# Multiple video element pointing to the same useRef() [React]

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to use the same `videoRef` on 2 elements?

Intended outcome: displaying 2 videos in 2 different `<video>`, pointing to the same `videoRef` on the same page concurrently.

```js
const videoRef = useRef();
const videoRef2 = useRef();

return (
  <div>
    {/* ... a video (videoRef) at top */}
    <video
      videoRef={videoRef}
    />
    {/* ... somehere else on the same page, the same video (videoRef) */}
    <video
      videoRef={videoRef}
    />
    {/* ... another video (videoRef2) */}
    <video
      videoRef={videoRef2}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is a possible thing to do
but there's a good way to handle [this](https://jsfiddle.net/d4twzfcv/)

```
const videoRefs = useRef([React.createRef(), React.createRef()]);

<video
   ref={videoRefs.current[0]}
/>
....
<video
   ref={videoRefs.current[1]}
/>
```

Or may be as [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a76ysp8o/):

```
const videoRefs = useRef([]);

<video
  ref = {el => videoRefs.current[0] = el}
/>
....
<video
  ref = {el => videoRefs.current[1] = el}
/>
```

[check this out too](https://erikmartinjordan.com/multiple-refs-array-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

- No. You can't use a reference to 2 elements because each element which is rendered in the real DOM is unique. videoRef will refer to second `<video>`